# how to store store flv file to array using C#

Tags: c#, flv

I have a flv file and I want to store it in array to do some operations in this array .
how to store store flv file to array using C#?

Comment: Do you mean a reference to the file or its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read a file into a byte array.

```
byte[] myArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"myFlvFile.flv");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep a reference/object, then you can probably take the stream and store it in the array. or you can read it to a byte array and you can have an array of byte array.